# How to inherit functions from a parent component in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to angular2, feel free to help me tune my vocabulary / terminology

I have a class that is composed of two directives like so:

in `parent.component.ts`, the `Parent` is made up of `Foo` and `Bar`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  directives: [Foo, Bar]
  ...
  template: require('./parent.html')
})
export class Parent {
  ...
}
```

in `Foo.component.ts`, we define `Foo`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  directives: [],
  ...
})
export class Foo {
  ...
  browse() {
    this.router.navigate(['/pages/somewhere', []]);
  }
}
```

in `Bar.component.ts`, we define `Bar`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bar',
  directives: [],
  ...
})
export class Bar {
  ...
  browse() {
    this.router.navigate(['/pages/somewhere', []]);
  }
}
```

in both the html templates for `Foo` and `Bar`, I want to use a click event (`browse()`) that does the same thing. I have it working like above, but there is repeated code in the definitions of both `Foo` and `Bar` that could be defined once in `Parent`

How might this inheritance look?

Comment: In my experience communication between parent and child is best through Service. You could also define `browse()` in a service and use it in both components

Comment: Do you want to access both browser methods from parent or you want to make it one browser method that can be accessed from parent and does the same thing for both components??????

Comment: @BojanKogoj I created a service and that works, thanks.

Comment: @micronyks The `Parent` component is basically a wrapper around `Foo` and `Bar`. Everything on the page is either defined in `Foo` or in `Bar`. So, if I understand your clarification correctly, I want one browser method defined once that can be accessed from both of the components that make up the parent.

Comment: Then you have to go for `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service, but it seems like it's nicer to keep this in the components unless you're using it in components everywhere. The canonical way to do this it with an `Output()` on the child components. In the child component you bind the `(click)` to the `browse()` function.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'bar',
   directives: [],
    ...
})
export class Bar {
    @Output() browse: EventEmitter<Node> = new EventEmitter<Node>();

    ...
    browse() {
       this.browse.emit(/*some data could be passed here*/)
    }
  }
```

In the parent template:

```
<bar (browse)="goSomewhere($event)" neolabel="Company"></bar>
```

And Component:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'parent',
   directives: [Foo, Bar]
   ...
   template: require('./parent.html')
 })
export class Parent {
   goSomewhere(event){this.router.navigate(['/pages/somewhere', []]);}
...
}
```

This keeps a single function in the parent, but keeps it together with logic of the interface.